# Image doesn't show up in img tag

Tags: html, image

I have a very strange problem with some images that I put on my website.
There are a few similar images, but in separate folders. These in folder "xxx" don't show(like they were missing, but they're not) when I put them into `<img src="http://example.com/imgs/xxx/xyz.png">`, but those in all other folders, f.e. in "yyy", show correctly on the page `<img src="http://example.com/imgs/yyy/zyx.png">`

When I open the links via "Check Element" in Google Chrome, via just source code in any web browser, or even when I manually write URL adress pointing to them, they are being shown in the web browser.

What is wrong then? They normally show in given adress, but they are missing when put in IMG tag.

I guess there might be something wrong with images themselves.

Comment: Using developer toolbar in browser or a tool like Fiddler, compare the network requests and responses in the two cases. There may be an error response returned that can help you solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried to make a JSFiddle ? I want to be sure what code you used. And be careful about the upper/lower-case letters too.